Is a catapult takeoff safer than a normal takeoff?
With all the increasing interest lately around on Urban Air Mobility UAM, AAM, VTOL and STOL Short Takeoff and Landing, I thought if the aircraft carrier catapult takeoff functionality could be part of these new VTOL/STOL urban airport designs that are being conceptualized these days.
I thought if as part of reducing the runway length requirements a catapult could be installed. So I wondered, safety always being the no 1 requirement if, are there more accidents on catapults takeoffs than with normal takeoff and if it would make sense using a catapult for UAM STOL?

Interestingly, the first use of a catapult to launch an aircraft was with the Wright Flyer...  https://www.wright-brothers.org/History_Wing/Wright_Story/Inventing_the_Airplane/Little_More_Oomph/Wright_Catapult.htm

On a carrier, a catapult takeoff is slightly safer than a ski jump takeoff. The catapult gives you extra energy, not much, about an extra 4 seconds of flight. With margins as tight as they are on a carrier takeoff, these four seconds can make a life or death difference.
A carrier takeoff cannot be aborted once the catapult goes off. A plunge into the drink is invariably fatal. The only way to abort is to eject and lose the plane. It happens, and naval aviation hull loss rates are two orders of magnitude higher than commercial.
Things are different on dry land. There, the takeoff roll is used to check if the aircraft is behaving normally, and if it isn't, there are two decision speeds: ~80 kts to reject for any issue, and V1 at 120-160 for critical problems. Aborting problem takeoffs is vital for achieving one-in-a-million or better crash rate expected of commercial flight.
The reasons catapults aren't and are not likely to ever be used for passenger flight on land are exactly the same as why more affordable ski jump ramps also aren't used - they lack this margin of safety. To restore it, you'd need to bring the runway up to nearly the same balanced field length as without a catapult.
However, assisted takeoff isn't entirely unused on land. It's common for gliders to be winch-launched, which is basically a low-tech catapult, but can be aborted mid-launch, and it's common to catapult launch UAVs. These risks are mitigated or accepted: for gliders, the engine is optional and it's a sport, and drones are just hardware.
Also, if a runway's too short for a conventional takeoff, is too short for a safe landing. You want a margin before and after the perfect touchdown point, and enough length for a touch-and-go if you touch down too late or too softly. Carriers use arrestor wires or maneuvers like SRVL, both with high deceleration and little margin for error. Naval aviators have ejection seats, and it's still a high-risk occupation even by military standards.
While urban air mobility is likely to remain a pipe dream for a long time, its possible use of assisted takeoff hinges on whether a higher loss rate is acceptable. For delivery drones it's "yes", for enthusiasts "possibly", but for common passengers, an almost certain "no". Even if ejection seats were fitted, they're not a 100% save and too dangerous for the general public.

The other significant reason for not using catapults is that the runway is also needed for landing, and at a similar length.

@MikeB Well, you could cable-trap the STOLs. Just make sure to only serve oatmeal aboard.

@Therac I concur with MikeB. Doesn't a landing with arresting gear like a tail hook need unusual skill, and isn't it unusually prone to failure? When you start you have all the time in the world to position the plane and make sure everything is attached and ready. When you land, not so much.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica You are right, these landings take skill to nail. But I'd expect 2050s automation to help. Also, in a flying aircraft, you have more options, like diverting to a real airport, or a barricade traps as a last resort.

Winch launching doesn't have the same dangers as catapults, because you can abort a winch launch at any time. Very rarely manned gliders can be bungee launched, which is essentially a catapult. https://www.a-e-g.org.uk/the-bungee.html Happened to me in an air cadet  T38 Grasshopper in the seventies.

Another feature of carrier operations is that wouldn't usually be anything past the end of the carrier's runway that one would worry about damaging.  In most scenaios where a land-based runway would need to be unusually short, a failed takeoff or landing would jeopardize more than just the plane and pilot.

A catapult needs both more infrastructure on the ground, and a much stronger airframe.
Both of those things mean much more money.
Catapults work on a Navy carrier, because there is literally no other option. Runway length is rarely that much of a limiting factor with an airport.

Thanks WPNSGuy, I want to focus the question on safety and practicality in the aviation sense(maybe ignoring the obvious costs, though actually that could be argued because you could compare the cost of a catapult system vs cost of bigger land). Please note that UAM is aiming for really high dense cities, some of these airports are to be constructed on very tight spaces, some even on rooftops.

Given a rooftop catapult takeoff...where are you going to land? Arresting hook capture on that rooftop is unfriendly to regular passengers.

@Gabe: Short takeoff / vertical landing is a thing some military aircraft do.  IDK how plausible it would be for civilian craft (weight, power-to-weight ratio at landing weight, extra flying skills needed(?), safety of basically hovering - if anything fails and you don't have an ejection seat, you're falling from too low to gain speed and glide, but a hundred or two hundred feet are still a long way).  If viable, that could let you land on something the size of a catapult strip without a tailhook sudden stop.

In short
Between the title and the body of your post, you ask disconnected questions about catapult safety and catapult use in urban air mobility.

A takeoff with a catapult is not safer than regular takeoff.

UAM projects don't rely on landing strips, they are based on vertical takeoff and landing, and electric rotorcraft.

Catapults are not helpful in vertical takeoff.



1. Catapult safety

Is a catapult takeoff safer than a normal takeoff?

No. If a catapult is needed to take off, it's because the aircraft is not able to safely reach the minimum speed using the available runway length. Using a catapult is not a way of adding safety, it's rather a way of making possible what is otherwise impossible. This impossible-made-possible comes with its own problems and risks.
Problems appear when the catapult cannot deliver the expected acceleration, when it blocks abruptly or when the aircraft cannot be uncoupled from the catapult shuttle, etc. These are additional risks compared to a regular takeoff.
Limiting these risks requires a reliable design, frequent inspections and continuous maintenance, meaning additional costs for the operator and for the customers. This is clearly not compatible with the UAM economic model.

2. Catapult and UAM projects

[Whether] it would make sense using a catapult for UAM STOL.

I would say it doesn't make sense. UAM projects don't rely on horizontal takeoff or landing, nor on catapults. UAM projects I'm aware of use electric rotorcraft taking off and landing vertically. Such aircraft known as eVTOL, are for example already used by Volocopter, or planned by Airbus.
They take off from "vertiports" (low cost heliports) and rooftops in city centers. In case of heavy wind, a vertical catapult adapted to eVTOL might provide a last resort way to take off, but this advantage is lost for landing. In this case, an eVTOL aircraft just stay on the ground.
UAM is "urban" mobility. In many parts of the world, e.g. in Europe, it's difficult to convince people to accept more noise or pollutants, so the usual argument to get authorization for eVTOL aircraft in urban areas is they can be used to quickly deliver medical supplies.
However this pretext doesn't change the actual business model which is to provide air taxis to people in a hurry, or pizzas and other cargo to the mass. These actual applications are intended to compete with land vehicles, not to save lives, so their cost must be low. Hence they cannot depend on usual aircraft landing strips, even short, they must be eVTOL.
If a catapult was ever required for eVTOL, it would have to be vertical, with some inconvenience:

Electric rotors would need to be adapted to bear the acceleration and allowed to rotate faster than their motors.

Taxi passengers would feel a negative acceleration, in the body axis (from head to feet), which is more difficult to stand than an orthogonal acceleration, and at the same time the passengers can't be lying on their back like astronauts.



I would imagine a eVTOL catapult could still be horizontal: helping the helicopter (which a eVTOL is) out of the danger zone without going through HOGE: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/54637/30268
